# Silverlight object overflow in IE11

Tags: silverlight, scroll, internet-explorer-11

The below code we are using for silver light image display in a div. It's working fine in IE8. But we have an issue with IE11. The image overlapping from the parent div it's not coming inside the div. Can any one fix this issue?

```
<div id="imgDiv" class="divBrd" style="width: 600px; height: 247px; overflow: auto;">
  <div id="tr2">
    <div id="divImage" onclick="clipimage(this);" style="overflow: hidden; width: 790px; height: 250px;">
      <object type="application/x-silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight," id="divImageID" width="780" height="250px">
        <param name="background" value="#ffffff">
        <param name="Stretch" value="Fill">
        <param name="source" value="../ClientBin/ImageHand.xap?v=7af70000-adb3-4167-b945-bf67a28a2186">
        <param name="initParams" value="PageId=1,SeqNo=3,SubSeqNo=0,Width=780,Height=250,Container=divImage">
        <param name="windowless" value="true">
        <param name="maxFramerate" value="24">
      </object>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Pandiyan

Comment: "*The below code*" -> *what* code?

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question to show the code. Without proper formatting, it is not visible.

Comment: My edit was approved 37 minutes ago, and the code is now visible.

Comment: When I said "*I submitted an edit*" I mean that I modified your question. When you originally posted it the code that you wrote was not visible. I made it visible (which is why it says "edited 1 hour ago" at the bottom of your question). If you click on [that link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29651037/revisions) it will show you what I did. I have no answers for you - my only input was to make it so that others could see your code and help you.